# Access nested joins with multiple where's possible?

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have this SQL statement which is close to what I want:

```
SELECT CustomerList.*, Sales.Sales, Sales.MonthYear
FROM (CustomerList INNER JOIN WhoBuysWhat ON CustomerList.CustomerID = WhoBuysWhat.CustomerID) LEFT JOIN Sales ON CustomerList.CustomerID = Sales.CustomerID
WHERE WhoBuysWhat.ProductID=2
ORDER BY CustomerList.CustomerName;
```

That gives me all the customers that buy a certain product line and any sales from the Sales table for that product line. But what I want is to add another WHERE statement. I want the first INNER JOIN to give me all the customers that buy productID 2. Then I want to Left Join the sales for ones that match sales.monthyear=#1/1/2015#. So I tried this (in different ways):

```
SELECT CustomerList.*, Sales.Sales, Sales.MonthYear
FROM ((CustomerList INNER JOIN WhoBuysWhat ON CustomerList.CustomerID = WhoBuysWhat.CustomerID) WHERE WhoBuysWhat.ProductID=2) LEFT JOIN Sales ON CustomerList.CustomerID = Sales.CustomerID
WHERE Sales.MonthYear=#1/1/2015#
ORDER BY CustomerList.CustomerName;
```

And that doesn't work. If I do this:

```
WHERE WhoBuysWhat.ProductID=2 AND Sales.MonthYear=#1/1/2015#
```

OR

```
WHERE Sales.ProductID=2 AND Sales.MonthYear=#1/1/2015#
```

It only gives me the customers that have sales in that month. I want ALL customers that buy that line and ANY sales for a GIVEN month. Is that possible in 1 SQL statement? Do I need to use AS for the first joined tables? I cannot find anything that will help me.

J_K_M_A_N

EDIT:
This is the final working SQL statement if anyone cares or needs help later.

```
SELECT CustomerList.*, Sales.SalesID, Sales.Sales, WhoBuysWhat.EntryID, WhoBuysWhat.Active
FROM (CustomerList INNER JOIN WhoBuysWhat ON CustomerList.CustomerID = WhoBuysWhat.CustomerID)
LEFT JOIN Sales ON (CustomerList.CustomerID = Sales.CustomerID AND Sales.MonthYear=#1/1/2015# AND Sales.ProductID=2)
WHERE WhoBuysWhat.ProductID=2
ORDER BY WhoBuysWhat.Active, CustomerList.CustomerName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and you want to filter some records from *Right* table then you need to move the right table **filter** to `ON` condition else `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will be implicitly converted to `INNER JOIN`

To make it short, `WHERE` clause you **reject** rows with `NULL` which are produced by `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for *non matching records*

```
SELECT customerlist.*, 
       sales.sales, 
       sales.monthyear 
FROM   (customerlist 
        INNER JOIN whobuyswhat 
                ON customerlist.customerid = whobuyswhat.customerid) 
       LEFT JOIN sales 
              ON (customerlist.customerid = sales.customerid 
                 AND sales.monthyear = #1/1/2015#) 
WHERE WhoBuysWhat.ProductID=2
ORDER  BY customerlist.customername;
```

Comment: I tried that and all I got was "Join Expression Not Supported". I tried it in both Access 2000 (Old, I know) and VB Net accessing that database. Both gave the same error. Does it not work on a version that old? It doesn't seem to like anything after the AND on the second join.

Comment: I got it working by using () around the ON AND part. So now I have this:

`SELECT CustomerList.*, Sales.SalesID, Sales.Sales, Sales.MonthYear
FROM (CustomerList INNER JOIN WhoBuysWhat ON CustomerList.CustomerID = WhoBuysWhat.CustomerID) LEFT JOIN Sales ON (CustomerList.CustomerID = Sales.CustomerID AND Sales.MonthYear=#1/1/2015#)
WHERE WhoBuysWhat.ProductID=2
ORDER BY CustomerList.CustomerName;`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I had to change this a little bit because the INNER JOIN was matching everything in Sales as long as the date was correct so I had to add another AND and match Sales.ProductID also. It was not getting to the WHERE WhoBuysWhat.ProductID=2 before matching any sales in that month with the same CustomerID. Now it works perfectly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want in MS Access using a subquery:

```
SELECT cl.*, s.sales,  s.monthyear 
FROM (customerlist as cl INNER JOIN
      whobuyswhat as wbw
      ON cl.customerid = wbw.customerid
     ) LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT s.*
      FROM sales as s
      WHERE s.monthyear = #1/1/2015#
     ) as s
     ON (cl.customerid = s.customerid 
WHERE wbw.ProductID = 2
ORDER BY cl.customername;
```